# Weird behaviour of loss function in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nan, loss-function

I'm computing a custom cost function that is simply taking the exponential of cross-entropy divided by a parameter \eta. During the first iterations (around 20), the training loss is decreasing, but after that, I get suddenly a nan, which I don't understand why is happening.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
e_loss = []
eta = 2 #just an example of value of eta I'm using 
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
for e in range(epoch):
    train_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        client_model.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = client_model(data)
        loss = torch.exp(criterion(output, target)/eta) # this is the line where I input my custom loss function
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)
    train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader) # average losses
    e_loss.append(train_loss)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly using `exp` is quite unstable when the input is unbounded. Cross-entropy loss can return very large values if the network predicts very confidently the wrong class (b/c -log(x) goes to inf as x goes to 0). A single inaccurate prediction by your model like this can result in numerical precision that would cause gradients to go to nan, which will immediately cause weights and outputs of your model to become nan.

For example

```py
>>> import torch
>>> import torch.nn.functional as F
>>> torch.exp(F.cross_entropy(torch.tensor([[-50.0, 50.0]]), torch.tensor([0])))
tensor(inf)
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Do you think I should consider a different loss function? or maybe choose a value of eta in a way to make the input bounded?

Comment: I don't actually see why you wouldn't just use cross-entropy loss directly. It is generally well behaved and standard for classification problems. As for modifying eta, that may be plausible but i can't see how you could guarantee stability. As your network trains longer it tends to give more confident predictions. Regardless of how large you make eta it's always a risk that eventually it makes one massive error that causes everything to go to nan.

Comment: Actually, this has to do with making the predictions robust in some sense (it is a bit difficult to explain the context here) but simply taking the cross-entropy is in some sense less robust in the context of my problem. That is why I'm looking for ways to make it works. But I believe your answer gives me hints on how to solve the issue. Thanks!